# Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог видеть заказы других пользователей той группы в которой он состоит?

Tags: битрикс

Необходимо реализовать функционал для личного кабинета пользователя, чтобы зарегистрированный пользователь, который входит в группу, мог видеть в своем личном кабинете не только свои заказы, но и заказы других участников группы.
Например пользователь привязан к группе Фирма 1 и он видит заказы других

Я так думаю надо копать в сторону класса Sale\Order
Возможно, как то через Битрикс API можно получить список заказов пользователя, зная только его ID, либо зная ID группы пользователей, получить все заказы ее участников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала надо получить список групп пользователя. Для текущего пользователя можно так:

```
$arGroups = CUser::GetUserGroupArray();
```

Для любого пользователя по ID:

```
$arGroups = CUser::GetUserGroup($userId);
```

Обратите внимание, что таким образом мы получим все группы, в которые входит пользователь, там могут быть и стандартные, которые присваиваются всем зарегистрированным пользователям.

Далее получим всех пользователей, которые входят в эти группы:

```
$usersID = [];
if($arGroups) {
    $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(
        $by,
        $order,
        [
            'GROUPS_ID' => $arGroups,
            'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
        ],
        [
            'FIELDS' => [
                'ID'
            ]
        ]
    );
    while ($user = $rsUsers->Fetch()) {
        $usersID[] = $user['ID'];
    }
}
```

Ну а теперь надо найти все заказы, которые принадлежат этим пользователям. Тут 2 варианта.
1. Если надо получить объект DB\Result с заказами, то делаем так:

```
if($usersID) {
    $rsOrders = \Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList([
        'filter' => [
            'USER_ID' => $usersID
        ],
        'order' => [
            'ID' => 'DESC'
        ]
    ]);
    while ($order = $rsOrders->fetch())
    {
        //тут массив одного заказа
    }
}
```

2. Если нужны готовые объекты заказов, то делаем так:

```
if($usersID) {
    $rsOrders = \Bitrix\Sale\Order::loadByFilter([
        'filter' => [
            'USER_ID' => $usersID
        ],
        'order' => [
            'ID' => 'DESC'
        ]
    ]);
    foreach($rsOrders as $order) {
        //тут объект одного заказа
    }
}
```